# pandas.core.series.series to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have this code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 'Falconiformes', 389.0),
               ('bird', 'Psittaciformes', 24.0),
               ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 80.2),
               ('mammal', 'Primates', np.nan),
               ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 58)],
              index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey', 'leopard'],
              columns=('class', 'order', 'max_speed'))
```

And I want to regroup the sames values so :

```
gp = df.groupby(['class', 'order','max_speed'])["class"].size().frame()
```

I got this :

```
                                 class
class  order          max_speed       
bird   Falconiformes  389.0          1
       Psittaciformes 24.0           1
mammal Carnivora      58.0           1
                      80.2           1
```

I put it on a html file, but what is displayed is just the last column while I want the first three. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the flag `index=True` in your case, since other 3 columns are in the index when you applied `groupby`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('bird', 'Falconiformes', 389.0),
           ('bird', 'Psittaciformes', 24.0),
           ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 80.2),
           ('mammal', 'Primates', np.nan),
           ('mammal', 'Carnivora', 58)],
          index=['falcon', 'parrot', 'lion', 'monkey', 'leopard'],
          columns=('class', 'order', 'max_speed'))
```

```
> df

        class   order           max_speed
falcon  bird    Falconiformes   389.0
parrot  bird    Psittaciformes  24.0
lion    mammal  Carnivora       80.2
monkey  mammal  Primates        NaN
leopard mammal  Carnivora       58.0
```

```
gp = df.groupby(['class', 'order','max_speed'])["class"].size().to_frame()
```

```
                                             class
class            order           max_speed  
bird             Falconiformes   389.0         1
                 Psittaciformes  24.0          1
mammal           Carnivora       58.0          1
                                 80.2          1
```

```
# All columns are printed in html
gp.to_html('D:/sample.html', index=True)

# Only last column, which is not in index gets printed in HTML.
gp.to_html('D:/sample.html', index=False)
```

**Edit**

> I have this error : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

The above error is a `decoding` error since you have imported excel from a file with a different encoding. To resolve this, pass the proper encoding format using the `encoding` flag.

In your case,

```
gp.to_html('C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\sample.html', index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have this error : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

Comment: Where in the code-segment you're getting the above error? Are you reading any excel via `read_csv` or `read_excel` methods?

Comment: the code-segment is this one : gp.to_html('C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\sample.html', index=True). I am reading from a excel

Comment: try passing flag `encoding='utf-8'` in the `to_html` function, i.e, gp.to_html('C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\sample.html', index=True, encoding='utf-8')